# Don't understand immutable objects

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngxs

I'm using `Ngxs` and discovered `developmentMode`.
I turned it on and I have some new errors that I don't understand.

In my store I have filters. I've made a facade function that gets them and adjust.

```
filterBarFiltrySnapshot(obiektId: Obiekty): any[] {
    let filtry = this.store.selectSnapshot((state: AppStateModel) => state.obiektyConfig[obiektId].filterBarFiltry);
    if (filtry) {
      filtry = filtry.map(item => {
        if (item.formValue) {
          Object.values(item.formValue).forEach(item2 => {
            item2.value = this.wstawianieWartosciService.wstaw(item2.value, obiektId);
          });
        }
        return item;
      });
    }
    return filtry;
  }
```

Typescript says that `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'value' of object '[object Object]'`.

But why? `this.store.selectSnapshot` returns array and shouldn't it be a copy of this in store?
Event when I change code to this:

```
let filtry = [
    ...this.store.selectSnapshot((state: AppStateModel) => state.obiektyConfig[obiektId].filterBarFiltry)
];
```

there still is error.

How to change code to meet immutable restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

The call to `store.selectSnapShot` will return *the* state, not a copy of it.  So if you modify the returned object(s) then it will break immutability of the state - which is why you see the error returned by the framework.

I'm not too clear on exactly what your filters function is trying to do but what it *can't* do is modifiy the current state.  It could project a view of it based on a filter value `obiektId`|`objectId` ?

Additionaly - here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247260/binding-to-state-is-this-expected-behaviour) I posted a while back re: state modifications.

It's also worth nothing that there are new features in the NGXS pipeline coming to make it easier to work with immutable state - see the latest [post](https://medium.com/ngxs/ngxs-state-operators-8b339641b220) from the NGXS team.

Comment: If `selectShapshot` is not a copy I can make a one `let filtry = [
    ...this.store.selectSnapshot((state: AppStateModel) => state.obiektyConfig[obiektId].filterBarFiltry)
];` but it still throws the same error.

Comment: I guess you should be able to copy that via spread operator .. depends on `filterBarFiltry` is that an object? You might still have a ref to the original state

Comment: try this
`let filtry = {...this.store.selectSnapshot((state: AppStateModel) => state.obiektyConfig[obiektId].filterBarFiltry) }`