# @Select of nested object and immutability of state

Tags: angular, immutability, deep-copy, state-management, ngxs

I am using NGXS for a while and found that if you use an object or array in @Select return it can break the immutability of the sate in the component.

Example:

```
state: AppStateModel = {
  justValue: true,
  complexObject: { a:1, b:2}
}
```

and then two selectors:

```
// Here in a component we will get access to object by link and can modify it in state without patchState or setState
  @Selector()
  static getComplexObject(state: AppStateModel) {
    return state.complexObject;
  }

// That will work fine since JS will return it as a value (simple types) not a link
  @Selector()
  static getJustValue(state: AppStateModel) {
    return state.justValue;
  }
```

I see the solution such as:

```
  // Here we can apply DeepCopy method to decople object from the state, and keep immutability no matter what happens in the components
  @Selector()
  static getComplexObject(state: AppStateModel) {
    return clone(state.complexObject);
  }
```

My question is it the right way to go? or Ngxs has some build-in solution for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should only change state in an action.

Comment: hey, thanks! The question is more how to be sure that state is will not be changed in a component, how to protect this on a state level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could for instance `Object.freeze()` in dev mode
https://medium.com/ngxs/immutable-state-in-ngxs-part-i-ba318bfc5bb3

Comment: Thanks, that exactly that I was looking. Also, I found that NGXS has DeveloperMode where they do it under the hood (deepFreeze) and throw an error if you try to change state property directly  . Topic here: https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1212